# Melt dataframe with first two rows as variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

apologies but this has me stumped, I thought I could pass the following dataframe into a simple pd.melt using iloc to reference my varaibles but it wasn't working for me (i'll post the error in a moment)

sample df

```
Date,     0151,        0561,       0522,   0912
0,Date,     AVG Review,  AVG Review, Review, Review 
1,Date      NaN          NaN          NaN    NaN
2,01/01/18  2            2.5          4        5
```

so as you can see, my ID as in the top row, the type of review is in the 2nd row, the date sits in the first column and the observations of the review are in rows on the date.

what I'm trying to do is melt this df to get the following

```
ID,   Date,     Review,        Score
0151, 01/01/18, Average Review 2
```

I thought I could be cheeky and just pass the following

pd.melt `pd.melt(df,id_vars=[df.iloc[0]],value_vars=df.iloc[1] )`

but this threw the error `'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

I've had a look at similar answers to pd.melt and perhaps reshape or unpivot? but I'm lost on how I should proceed.

any help is much appreciated.

Edit for Nixon :

My first Row has my unique IDs

2nd row has my observation, which in this case is a type of review (average, normal)

3rd row onward has the variables assigned to the above observation - lets call this score.

1st column has my dates which have the score across by row.

Comment: "and the observations of the review are in rows on the date", please can you better explain the structure of your data?

Comment: @Nixon Done, hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: How you constructed your dataframe would really help here. I'm not sure what's an index or column versus values in the dataframe.

Comment: hey @busybear I did want to construct the same DF in Pandas but wasn't sure how to go about it. But assume there is no index so when I load the DF pandas creates one.

Comment: Are you manually creating this dataframe or importing from a file or something? Either way, there should be clear row and column indices. It's odd that 'Date' appears three times and the third row is just NaN. Carefully creating your dataframe should be your first step.

Comment: @BusyBear It is odd indeed, this is data pulled from Supermetrics, I don't work in digital so this is outside of my domain but I've been tasked with cleaning this data up. on my Raw data import Date is there thrice, and once with NaN values all the way across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to `pd.melt` is to set your rows as column levels of a multiindex and then `stack` them. Your metadata will be stored as an index rather than column though. Not sure if that matters.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Date',     '0151',        '0561',       '0522',   '0912'],
    ['Date',     'AVG Review',  'AVG Review', 'Review', 'Review'],
    ['Date',     'NaN',         'NaN',        'NaN',    'NaN'],
    ['01/01/18', 2,             2.5,          4,        5],
])

df = df.set_index(0)
df.index.name = 'Date'
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.iloc[0, :], df.iloc[1, :]], names=['ID', 'Review'])
df = df.drop(df.index[[0, 1, 2]])

df.stack('ID').stack('Review')
```

Output:

```
Date      ID    Review    
01/01/18  0151  AVG Review      2
          0522  Review          4
          0561  AVG Review    2.5
          0912  Review          5
dtype: object
```

You can easily revert index to columns with `reset_index`.

Comment: this gets me very close, however, a few problems - my columns are already set as the ID,s thus using the iloc removes them, and the final line of code throws `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` this error. However, your code works on my example and the problem is my explaining my issue. let me think about this and play around and I'll re-ask in a better manner. Thank you for your time.

Comment: That won't be too hard to accommodate. You'll just need to set your multiindex as `[df.columns, df.iloc[0, :]]` instead. There are a few other changes that you would need to make it work as well.